# Immutable C++ String class

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, immutability

I have project where I will need to create lots of immutable strings. If I am using `std::string`, which has huge overhead - about 60-70% against `const char *`. On a 64-bit machine, the current implementation uses 8 bytes for the class + the `const char *` size. This is the same size as it would be with plain C.

I will also do optimization with union and will put small strings into the pointer itself.

I need to know if I am on right track.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string.h>

class String{
public:
    String(){};

    String(const char *s) : _data(__dup(s)){};

    String(const String & other) : String( other.c_str() ){};

    String(String && other) = default;

    String & operator=(String other){
        std::swap(_data, other._data);
        return *this;
    }



    const char *c_str() const{
        return _data.get();
    }

    int cmp(const String & other) const{
        if (c_str() == nullptr)
            return other ? -1 : 0;

        return strcmp(*this, other);
    }

    operator bool() const{
        return c_str();
    }

    operator const char *() const{
        return c_str();
    }



    bool operator == (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) == 0;
    }

    bool operator != (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) != 0;
    }

    bool operator > (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) > 0;
    }

    bool operator >= (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) >= 0;
    }

    bool operator < (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) < 0;
    }

    bool operator <= (const String & other) const{
        return cmp(other) <= 0;
    }

private:
    static char *__dup(const char *s){
        auto size = strlen(s);
        char *copy = new char[size];
        memcpy(copy, s, size);
        return copy;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> _data;
};



void p(String &s){
    printf("%s\n", s ? (const char *) s : "[null]");
}

int main(){
    String s1;          p(s1);
    String s2  = { "hello" };   p(s2);
    String s3a = s2;        p(s3a);
    String s3  = std::move(s3a);    p(s3);
    s1 = s3;            p(s1);
    s1 = "hi";          p(s1);

    String a = "aaaa";
    String b = "bbbb";
    String c = "aaaa";

    printf("%s %s\n", a == c ? "Y" : "N", "Y");
    printf("%s %s\n", a == b ? "Y" : "N", "N");
    printf("%s %s\n", a != b ? "Y" : "N", "Y");
    printf("%s %s\n", a <  b ? "Y" : "N", "Y");
    printf("%s %s\n", a >  b ? "Y" : "N", "N");
    printf("%s %s\n", a <= b ? "Y" : "N", "Y");
    printf("%s %s\n", a >= b ? "Y" : "N", "N");
    printf("%s %s\n", a <= c ? "Y" : "N", "Y");
    printf("%s %s\n", a >= c ? "Y" : "N", "Y");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want `__dup` to return something, right?  Also, I generally wouldn't recommend using `printf`

Comment: __dup() - is a mistake. found it, but forgot to re-post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Design

In modern standard libraries, `std::string` uses short string optimization, which allows to avoid heap allocations at all for string shorter then ~20 chars (on 64-bit machines). So you really want to measure performance, I am not readily convinced that your string offers performance improvement. Of course, for your specific use pattern it might, but you have to measure.

### `__dup` function

This is the most problematic part of the code.

- Apparently, you forgot to return value from `__dup` method *(now fixed)*.
- You must allocate one `char` more and fill it with zero. Or copy `size+1` characters from the source.
- Identifiers with leading double underscores or one leading underscore and a capital letter are reserved by the standard. You must not use such an identifier. It is enough that you already have put it into `private` section.

After the corrections, the function could look like this:

```
static char *dup(const char *s){
    auto size = strlen(s);
    char *copy = new char[size + 1];
    memcpy(copy, s, size + 1);
    return copy;
}
```

### Safety

Functions do not check for null pointers. This code will cause illegal memory access:

```
String x;
String y{x};
```

### Style

- You don't need semicolons after the member function definitions
- I would recommend not putting methods on a single line even if they have empty bodies.
- You can use C++ style headers `<cstring>` and `<cstdio>` instead of C-style ones.
- I would recommend to implement an `operator<<(std::ostream &, const String &)` so you could use your string together with iostreams.
- For testing, it is better to use a testing framework. Like boost.test, gtest, Catch etc.

Comment: thanks a lot! I noted the size and return error, but did not know this about identifiers. This explains why many people put underscore at the end, e.g. dup_(). I know GNU  std::string must have short string optimization, but when I did tested it, it never worked for me. Even standard malloc() can not get less than 24 bytes, std:string with "hello" (len=6), give me triple time an 40% more memory consumption than malloc() / memcpy(). I am really surprised Boost did not include string like mine.

Comment: GNU's glibc was non-conforming in this aspect until recently. Only in version 5.1 they changed from CoW to SSO strings. Before that they provided separate type `vstring` with SSO.

Comment: yep, gcc it is 5.1

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916358/immutable-strings-vs-stdstring). There are two links to existing implementations (although I have not had a look at these myself, and don't know if it's what are you looking for)

Comment: And here is another implementation: [cpp_immutable_string](https://github.com/cdmh/cpp_immutable_string)

Comment: cpp_immutable_string uses std::string inside

Comment: Indeed, so this library is not what you are looking for. As of why there are no such libraries, I think there are 2 reasons: null-terminated strings are considered bad, and it appears everyone uses `string_view` like solutions.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nmmmnu/3e7ed7e3e7e31a9efd23

Comment: just to be clear, you do not need to review it. I'll find any mistakes when I do proper tests. I'm sending it only if you are curious.